# Algorithm for market clearing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, discrete-mathematics, economics

I've got discrete step functions for supply and demand.  I'm searching for an algorithm to find the equilibrium price, The data are below in `R`, but a solution any language (or pseudo-code) is acceptable.

```
demand = data.frame(volume = c(8,2,3,1,1), price=c(1,2,3,4,5))
supply = data.frame(volume = c(3,2,4,2,3), price=c(5,4,3,2,1))

demand$volume <- cumsum(demand$volume)
supply$volume <- cumsum(supply$volume)

plot(demand, type="s")
lines(supply, type="s", col=3)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a point where qd=qs. I am not really a economics guy, but I remember qd=qs was the equilibrium point. What should be the output of the above case?

Comment: @Vidor Vistrom you are right, I've fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into a similar problem and found this great description: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYfbM56L-mE&ab_channel=31761-Renewablesinelectricitymarkets

You can motivate a similar analysis for your problem. Consider an LP formulation. Given the dual solution, you can find the market-clearing price as follows:

```
demand = data.frame(Type = "demand",Q = c(8,2,3,1,1), P=c(1,2,3,4,5))
supply = data.frame(Type = "supply",Q = c(3,2,4,2,3), P=c(5,4,3,2,1))
ds <- rbind(supply,demand)
```

By representing the problem from LP, do the following:

```
ds[ds$Type == "demand","Q"] <- ds[ds$Type == "demand","Q"]
ds[ds$Type == "supply","Q"] <- ds[ds$Type == "supply","Q"]

P_s <- ds[ds$Type == "supply","P"]
P_d <- ds[ds$Type == "demand","P"]
Q_s <- ds[ds$Type == "supply","Q"]
Q_d <- ds[ds$Type == "demand","Q"]
c_vec <- c(P_s,-P_d)
A_mat <- diag(length(c_vec))
b_vec <- c(Q_s,Q_d)
dir_1 <- rep("<=",length(b_vec))

A2_mat <- c(rep(1,length(Q_s)),rep(-1,length(Q_d)))
b2_vec <- 0

A_mat <- rbind(A_mat,A2_mat)
b_vec <- c(b_vec,b2_vec)
dir_1 <- c(dir_1,"=")

library(lpSolve)
sol <- lp ("min", c_vec, A_mat, dir_1, b_vec, compute.sens=TRUE)
price_mc <- sol$duals[nrow(ds) + 1] # extracts the dual, which corresponds to the price
```

In your example, the market-clearing price is $2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take *partial* `cumsum` volumes from opposite ends of the price range.

```
demand_cum = (15, 7, 5,  2,  1)
supply_cum = ( 3, 5, 9, 11, 14)
```

This shows you *total, cumulative* demand & supply at each price.
Now can you spot the equilibrium?